# How can I programmatically commit data from QTableWidget, which contain some items in editing state?

Tags: qt

How can I autocommit data from QTableWidget, that is in editing state, when I fire some command?

Assume, that there is some grid and data in it (editable thorough delegate that fires QComboBox editor). So, one starting to select option in combo, but do not finish editing, then hit some button, that executes action, that uses data from that combo, but new choise is not committed yet :\

How can I programmatically finish editing in table?

I mean some not strict 'loop all items and finish editing' way, that I consider as bad and ugly.

OOPS: worked too much, so, haven't realised, that there could be only one pending editor at time. Question is still here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a protected slot named "commitData" in the tableWidget. You can inherit from tableWidget, then add your own public method (or slot) and send a signal (or simply call commitData method) from there.
There is one problem. You'll need to provide the editor object, but tableWidget gives you no way to get the pointer you need.
If you're using your own createEditor method, you can save the pointer to the editor somewhere, where your method can get it. It's a hack, but it's the only way i know.

Comment: yes, that is thhe only way I know too, and it's somewhat hacky. But it seems, that o other way exists.:(

Answer (score 4):

The current editor does not seem to be accessible from outside of the view, but its content is committed when the current model index changes. So a simple way to force a commit seems to be to call

table->setCurrentIndex (QModelIndex ())

plus restoring your previous current index afterwards if the widget is not discarded yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question but it still came up quite high on Google so just in case anyone else needs the answer QTableView has a protected method

```
void currentChanged(const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous)
```

which causes the data to be commited and QTableWidget is built on QTableView so that should still work. I found this info on the [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/8536/how-to-commit-data-being-edited-in-qtableview-on-window-close/2).